# Maximum integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was following the article here on max integer value in JS.

http://blog.vjeux.com/2010/javascript/javascript-max_int-number-limits.html

It states that the bits available to significand is 52.

How then does it say that the max number is 2e53 -1 .

How can we even write 2e53 when that bit is not available ?

I don't quiet get it

Comment: There's always an implied 1 bit before the fractional part of the mantissa.

Comment: Which article? Please link it!

Comment: I'm not too sure about the javascript specifics but it sounds like this is not an integer, its a float.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation, specifically the mention of the "implicit bit"

Comment: see the new `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which article you read specifically, but hopefully this will help

```
Math.pow(2,53) - 1
// 9007199254740991
//                ^

Math.pow(2,53)
// 9007199254740992
//                ^

Math.pow(2,53) + 1
// 9007199254740992
//                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary floating-point numbers in the IEEE spec look like

> *s* ✕ 1.nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn ✕ 2^*exp*

The *s* bit is the sign bit; *exp* is the binary exponent. The mantissa bits, *n*, are implicitly the binary fraction of a number that starts with `1`.  That `1` is implicit, and does not have to be stored explicitly. That means that there are 52 explicit bits and 1 implicit bits, for a total of 53. The sign bit is separate. Thus, `2^53-1` covers all positive 53-bit values that can be represented exactly.

Answer (score -3):

It can be usefull library
[Big Integer](https://github.com/microshine/asn1js/blob/master/int10.js)

Comment: OP did not ask for a library.